# Check if a tree is a Perfect Tree

Tags: haskell, tree, boolean

I want to write a Haskell function that checks if a tree is a perfect tree. I know that a tree is perfect if all the leaves of the tree are at the same depth.

I know I would start off like this

`perfectTree :: Tree a -> Bool`

But seeing that my grasp on the actual definition isn't too strong, can anyone actually explain what a perfect tree is and how you would go about checking that a tree is perfect in Haskell

I should have included that I defined data Type as follows:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to define a helper function `perfectTreeHeight :: Tree a -> Maybe Int` that returns `Just` the height of the tree if it's perfect, or `Nothing` otherwise. This is much easier to implement since you actually get the heights from the recursive calls so you can compare them. (Hint: use do-notation)

`perfectTree` is then just a trivial wrapper around this function.

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

perfectTree :: Tree a -> Bool
perfectTree = isJust . perfectTreeHeight

perfectTreeHeight :: Tree a -> Maybe Int
perfectTreeHeight = ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to think recursively about this?

---

**Solution:** The subtrees of the tree must *all* be perfect trees. Also, the depths of those subtrees should be equal. **End.**

I hope this high level solution/idea helps. I avoided to give an actual definition of `perfectTree` because I lack the actual definition of a `Tree`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your tree looks something like this...

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

Now, we could define a recursive `height` function along these lines:

```
height :: Tree a -> Maybe Int
height (Leaf _) = Just 1
height (Branch a b) = ???
```

Ind the second case (???), we want to add one to the height of the subtrees, but only if they are perfect, and only if they have the same height. Let's define a helper function, `same`, which takes the heights of the subtrees, and returns a Maybe Int containing their height, but only if they are both perfect and have the same height.

```
same :: Eq a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
same (Just a) (Just b) = if a == b then Just a else Nothing
same _ _ = Nothing
```

Now we can finish the `height` function. All it needs to do is add 1 to the height of the subtrees.

```
height :: Tree a -> Maybe Int
height (Leaf _) = Just 1
height (Branch a b) = maybe Nothing (Just . (1+)) subTreeHeight
  where subTreeHeight = same (height a) (height b)
```

And here's how to use it.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let aTree = (Leaf 'a')
  print aTree
  print $ height aTree

  let bTree = Branch (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')
  print bTree
  print $ height bTree

  let cTree = Branch (Leaf 'a') (Branch (Leaf 'b') (Leaf 'c'))
  print cTree
  print $ height cTree

  let dTree = Branch (Branch (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')) (Branch (Leaf 'c') (Leaf 'd'))
  print dTree
  print $ height dTree
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Leaf 'a'
Just 1
Branch (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')
Just 2
Branch (Leaf 'a') (Branch (Leaf 'b') (Leaf 'c'))
Nothing
Branch (Branch (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')) (Branch (Leaf 'c') (Leaf 'd'))
Just 3
```

Comment: I should have included how I defined my tree. I edited my question based off my definition

Comment: Your definition of Tree is identical to my definition, except that I called the second constructor Branch and you called it Node. So it should be easy for you to modify the solution I presented.